# Thought on creating a searchable database

Tags: database, forms, database-design, user-experience

I guess what I need is two things. First a way to input data into an Excel like application or a form builder, then a way to search those entries. For example.. CAR PART put a car Part A into Field 1 the next Field 2 would be car Type, followed by make and model. The fields would need to be made into a form consisting of preset inputs such as ( Title/Type ) and (Variable Categories) so a drop down menu, icons, or checkboxes would help narrow down the list of results. What pieces need to be in place to build/use a lightweight database/application design like this that allows inputting new information and then being able to search for latet search for variables? Also is there any application that does this already, a programming code to learn, or estimated cost and requirements to have it built?

Answer (score -1):

First, there might be something off the shelf that does this already, and there are applications like this.  Microsoft's Access would be a good place to start to see if it would fit your needs -- you can build forms and store data without much programming effort.  As time goes on, you can scale up to a SQL Server.
It's not clear to me if your data is relational or not, and it might not matter much at first (any database will likely handle your queries to start).  I originally thought your data was not relational, but re-reading your post, I'm not so sure now.
If that doesn't work,  or you want more flexibility, then I'd start looking at NoSQL as an option.  Some good choices include Mongo and RavenDB (there are *many* others).
You can program it yourself with just about any major language -- some provide more or less functionality based on the tie-in to the data.

Comment: Thanks. The data is relational. Any chance I can find someone to build this for me? Microsoft access seems a bit heavy appwise i was hoping for something more lightweight. Also I need two things the form builder and a way to search form entries. Any tips for that?

Comment: What you need is not a complex job -- of course, I've been doing it for decades (including 15 years at Microsoft), so that's easy for me to say.  I honestly believe paying someone for this is a smart choice and it shouldn't be a lot for what you want.  IDK if you can email me from this platform, but I can hook you up by either doing the work myself or suggesting a colleague who I know can do it.  My LinkedIn is here:  https://www.linkedin.com/in/johnmasonatlanta.  You can shoot me a note there, if you want.